# Uploading image using VF page and Apex to S3

Tags: amazon-s3, salesforce, apex, visualforce

I have tried creating Visualforce Page and Apex that sends the image to Amazon S3 bucket, Though it upload successfully but when i viewed the image using the link from Amazon it shows box instead of the actual image uploaded. See image below

[image: Upon viewing the uploaded image]

Here is my Visualforce Code that sends the file to apex using javascript:

```
<input class="slds-input-custom" id="logo" name="bsLogo" type="file" />
<button id="submtBtn" onclick="toSubmit()" label="Submit" title="Submit" class="cSubmit"  >Submit</button>
<apex:form id="formId">
    <apex:actionFunction name="setParamAF" action="{!apexMethod}" rerender="panelId" status="checkingId" oncomplete="onloadCallback();">
            <apex:param name="vBusiLogo" value=""/>
    </apex:actionFunction>
</apex:form>

<script>
   function toSubmit(){
           reader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById('logo').files[0]);
           reader.onload = function(){
                 var dataURL = reader.result;
           setParamAF(dataURL);
    };
   }
   function onloadCallback(){
       alert('uploaded');
   }
</script>
```

The dataURL variable has these base64 value:
[image: dataURL base64 Value]

On the Apex class side, I have this code:

```
String busiLogo = '';
public static void apexMethod(){
  busiLogo = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('vBusiLogo');
  String logoName = 'image.png';
  String bucketname ='amazon-file-s3';
  String host = 's3-ap-sample-1.amazonaws.com';

  Blob beforeblob = Blob.valueOf(busiLogo);
  String attachmentBody = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(beforeblob);
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setMethod('PUT');
    req.setEndpoint('callout:AmazonS3' + '/' + logoName);
    req.setHeader('Host', bucketname + '.' + host);
    req.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueOf(attachmentBody.length()));
    req.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'UTF-8');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','image/png');
    req.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
    req.setHeader('Date', formattedDateString);
    req.setHeader('ACL', 'public-read-write');
    Blob blobFile = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(attachmentBody);
    req.setBodyAsBlob(blobFile);
    
    Http http = new Http();
    HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
}
```

Can you help me how will I send my actual image to s3 file, or where did I go wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that since the busiLogo variable is `base64` encoded, I can just decode it and remove the `"data:image/png;base64"`, from it. and then encode the value and send the encoded blob value to S3.